For normed spaces $ E=\{x\in X \mid \inf\{ \|x-e\| \mid e \in E \}=0 \} $
Let X be a normed vector space and $ E \subset X$
Prove that $$ E=\{x\in X \mid \inf\{ \|x-e\| \mid e \in E \}=0 \} $$
I tried to prove like this:
Let
$\begin{align*}
x \in E &\Rightarrow 0 \le \inf\{ \|x-e\| \mid e \in E \} \le \|x-x\|=0 \\
&\Rightarrow \inf\{ \|x-e\| \mid e \in E \}=0 \\
&\Rightarrow x \in \{x\in X \mid \inf\{ \|x-e\| \mid e \in E \}=0 \} \\
&\Rightarrow E \subset \{x\in X \mid \inf\{ \|x-e\| \mid e \in E \}=0 \}
\end{align*}$
Then I tried to prove that
$ \{x\in X \mid \inf\{ \|x-e\| \mid e \in E \}=0 \} \subset E $
but I can't see it.
Also, I found a counter example:
$ (\mathbb R , |.|) $  is a normed vector space. Let $E=(0,1)$
It's clear that
$ \inf\{ \|1-e\| \mid e \in E \}=0 $
But $ 1\notin E $
Is this question wrong? Or did I think wrong ?

The question is wrong. You have to change LHS to $\overline E$ to make it correct.

It is true that $E$ is contained in $\{x\in X : \inf \{\|x-e\| : e\in E \} = 0 \}$. You have also correctly found a counterexample for the original statement. What is worth noting in your counterexample is that $1$ is in the closure of $(0,1)$ with respect to $\mathbb{R}$. For the general case, it can be shown that the closure of $E$ in $X$, denoted by $\overline{E}$, is equal to $\{x\in X : \inf \{\|x-e\| : e\in E \} = 0 \}$.
There are many ways to show this. One way is to note that if $x\in X$, $x\in \overline{E}$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is some $e\in E$ such that $\|x-e\| < \varepsilon$. This holds if and only if $\inf\{\|x-e\| : e\in E \} = 0$.

I got it. Thank you
